# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Health Check UI is not working

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, health-check

i have developed an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Application with customized Health Check. It's perfectly working fine as shown below.

[image]

However, the UI is always empty as the /health-api always returns empty array.
[image]

[image]

It's in ASP.NET 3.1 Core application which can be located at https://github.com/prawin2k/HealhCheckMVC/tree/master/HealhCheckMVC

.NET Core version - 3.1 (MVC)
Healthchecks version - Latest
Operative system: Windows Server 2016
Others: Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 8):

In my case the health checks UI itself not launching and crashing the .net core 3.1 web API application.

**Error Message:**
*Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: HealthChecks.UI.Core.Notifications.IHealthCheckFailureNotifier Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: HealthChecks.UI.Core.Notifications.WebHookFailureNotifier': Unable to resolve service for type 'HealthChecks.UI.Core.Data.HealthChecksDb' while attempting to activate  'HealthChecks.UI.Core.Notifications.WebHookFailureNotifier'.)*

**Fix**: Add any [UI storage provider](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#Configuration) . In my case I have choosen **AddInMemoryStorage()**

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    
    services.AddHealthChecks() 
        .AddDbContextCheck<PollDbContext>() //nuget: Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore
        .AddApplicationInsightsPublisher(); //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Publisher.ApplicationInsights

    services.AddHealthChecksUI() //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI
        .AddInMemoryStorage(); //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.InMemory.Storage
        
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    
    app.UseHealthChecks("/healthcheck", new HealthCheckOptions
    {
        Predicate = _ => true,
        ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client
    });
    
    //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI
    app.UseHealthChecksUI(options =>
    {
        options.UIPath = "/healthchecks-ui";
        options.ApiPath = "/health-ui-api";
    });
    ...
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```json
"HealthChecks-UI": {
    "DisableMigrations": true,
    "HealthChecks": [
        {
            "Name": "PollManager",
            "Uri": "/healthcheck"
        }
    ],
    "Webhooks": [
        {
            "Name": "",
            "Uri": "",
            "Payload": "",
            "RestoredPayload": ""
        }
    ],
    "EvaluationTimeOnSeconds": 10,
    "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60,
    "MaximumExecutionHistoriesPerEndpoint": 15
}
```